# Laravel - Accessor only on certain API call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, accessor

I have a simple API end point in Laravel for a search function:

```
return User::where('name', 'like', "%".$request->name."%")
        ->with('teams')
        ->get();
```

This works, but the client doesn't want the ability to see the full email in the response. I could use an accessor, but that would mean the email is always returned masked in every request.

Can I make it so I only get the masked email in certain API calls?

Comment: What about looping over returned users and change thier emails (mask them) then return edited users to view ?!

Comment: I just ended up doing that :) I feel its not a nice way to do it but will do for now.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've implemented for this.